# Launch images xcode issue, Iphone 6s launched app zoomed

Tags: iphone, xcode, resolution, launch-screen

When I launch the app through the Xcode in my Iphone 6s, the app is being launched zoomed. The specific app is already on the app store with all the assets and launch images set correctly and everything was working fine. All the resolutions were correct for all IOS devices. But now, after I launched it again through the xcode as I want to make an update the app is being launched zoomed. Any ideas why this is happening? I managed to test it only in Iphone 6s.

Comment: Why are you using launch images instead of a single Launch Screen File?

Comment: I never used this way. I am not really sure how this is working. Is it easier? Or which is better?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me when I gave a wrong resolution to the splash image (750x1134 instead of 750x1334). I guess Xcode assumes you want to use the app with that resolution overall and adapts accordingly. Was fixed when I gave the correct resolution splash image.

Comment: after searching for a day i arrive at this which resolved the issue, thanks paris for the post

Answer (score 0):

At least I didn't find a solution and what caused this issue, but I used the storyboard file as a launch screen which was much easier to develop.